# JPA Converter in EJB JAR

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, ejb

I am trying to define a JPA `@Converter` for Joda-Time which gets put in an EJB JAR along with the result of the JPA `@Entity` and a `@Stateless` session bean like this:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateConverter implements
        AttributeConverter<LocalDate, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final LocalDate localDate) {
        if (localDate == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return localDate.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(final String dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return LocalDate.parse(dbData);
    }
}
```

I have a session bean that looks like:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class VenueTableModule {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public Bar foo() {
        final Bar bar = new Bar ();
        bar.name = "foo" + UUID.randomUUID();
        bar.startDate = LocalDate.now();
        em.persist(bar);
        em.flush();
        return bar;
    }
}
```

which fails on the `em.persist(bar)` line when I invoke it from the servlet.  The code works without the `em.*` lines I don't get the error when the converter, stateless session beans, etc. are moved to the web application which I know is allowed and I may have to do it.  So it appears that the `@Converter` is using a different class loader than the rest of the EJB jar.

I am using Glassfish 4.0, and I am not sure if it is a [bug GLASSFISH-21161](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21161) or if I am just doing something incorrectly.  However, [the code](https://github.com/trajano/jodatime-jpa-converter-example) I have seems to work with WildFly

Comment: If you could have posted the stacktrace, it would help check exactly what is the problem

Comment: Added the stack trace to the bug report

Answer (score 0):

The `AttributeConverter` is a Generic type class. See the Java Doc below:

```
/**
 * A class that implements this interface can be used to convert 
 * entity attribute state into database column representation 
 * and back again.
 * Note that the X and Y types may be the same Java type.
 *
 * @param <X>  the type of the entity attribute
 * @param <Y>  the type of the database column
 */
public interface AttributeConverter<X,Y>
```

Try changing your LocalDateConverter to

```
public class LocalDateConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, String>
```

where `LocalDate` is the type of the attribute in your entity bean and `String` is the type the database expects as a `varchar` or `char` or `text` field.

Comment: Nope, that was a problem with the Stack Overflow editor dropping the <> which have been there.